# UIBarButtonItem Appearance for NavigationControl affecting Toolbar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, uiappearance

I set a UIAppearance for a UIBarButtonItem in a UINavigationController like this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UINavigationController class],nil] setBackgroundImage:bimg forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UINavigationController class],nil] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, bimg.size.height*2) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

but it seems to be affecting UIBarButtonItems inside a UIToolBar as well.
what I want to do is , I have custom buttons in the navigationBar, but i'm using a UIToolbar above the keyboard and I want those buttons to remain stock iOS style.

Is there any way to revert the UIAppearance? Or can I explicitly set the UIAppearance of a UIBarButtonItem inside a UIToolbar to use default?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UINavigationBar` instead of `UINavigationController`:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class],nil] setBackgroundImage:bimg forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class],nil] setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, bimg.size.height*2) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```